# No such file or directory error in dpkg during apt-upgrade

Tags: 20.04, upgrade, dpkg

When I run `apt upgrade`, I get the following output:

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Calculating upgrade... Done
The following package was automatically installed and is no longer required:
  libllvm11
Use 'sudo apt autoremove' to remove it.
The following NEW packages will be installed:
  gir1.2-clutter-1.0 gir1.2-clutter-gst-3.0 gir1.2-cogl-1.0 gir1.2-coglpango-1.0 gir1.2-gtkclutter-1.0 libjcat1 libllvm12 linux-headers-5.4.0-81 linux-headers-5.4.0-81-generic
  linux-image-5.4.0-81-generic linux-modules-5.4.0-81-generic linux-modules-extra-5.4.0-81-generic
The following packages will be upgraded:
  alsa-ucm-conf base-files distro-info-data firefox firefox-locale-en fwupd fwupd-signed gnome-settings-daemon gnome-settings-daemon-common gnome-shell-extension-desktop-icons
  google-chrome-stable grub-common grub-pc grub-pc-bin grub2-common language-pack-en language-pack-en-base language-pack-gnome-en language-pack-gnome-en-base libdrm-amdgpu1
  libdrm-common libdrm-intel1 libdrm-nouveau2 libdrm-radeon1 libdrm2 libegl-mesa0 libexiv2-27 libfwupd2 libfwupdplugin1 libgbm1 libgl1-mesa-dri libgl1-mesa-glx libglapi-mesa
  libgles2-mesa libglx-mesa0 libssh-4 libssh-gcrypt-4 libssl1.1 libxatracker2 linux-firmware linux-generic linux-headers-generic linux-image-generic linux-libc-dev login
  mesa-va-drivers mesa-vdpau-drivers mesa-vulkan-drivers openssh-client openssl openvpn passwd python3-distupgrade ssh-askpass-gnome ubuntu-release-upgrader-core
  ubuntu-release-upgrader-gtk update-notifier update-notifier-common wireless-regdb xserver-common xserver-xephyr xserver-xorg-core xserver-xorg-legacy xwayland
64 upgraded, 12 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
12 standard security updates
Need to get 371 kB/382 MB of archives.
After this operation, 552 MB of additional disk space will be used.
Do you want to continue? [Y/n] Y
Get:1 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-updates/main amd64 libssh-4 amd64 0.9.3-2ubuntu2.2 [170 kB]
Get:2 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-updates/main amd64 libssh-gcrypt-4 amd64 0.9.3-2ubuntu2.2 [202 kB]
Fetched 371 kB in 1s (285 kB/s)           
Extracting templates from packages: 100%
Preconfiguring packages ...
setting xserver-xorg-legacy/xwrapper/allowed_users from configuration file
dpkg (subprocess): unable to execute split package reassembly (dpkg-split): No such file or directory
dpkg: error processing archive /var/cache/apt/archives/base-files_11ubuntu5.4_amd64.deb (--unpack):
 subprocess dpkg-split returned error exit status 2
Errors were encountered while processing:
 /var/cache/apt/archives/base-files_11ubuntu5.4_amd64.deb
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

However, the file does exist as shown here:

```
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root     60600 Aug  5 14:14 base-files_11ubuntu5.4_amd64.deb
```

Does anyone know what the missing file or directory could be, or how I could find it?

I have removed the file and it was automatically downloaded, so I assume it's a good copy.
I have tried purge, configure -a, and the other options I found at the site https://www.makeuseof.com/how-to-find-and-fix-broken-packages-on-linux/, but to no avail.

Any assistance would be greatly appreciated.

Randy

@kanehekili-- using Ubuntu 20.04 LTS; here is the output from `sudo blkid`:

```
/dev/sdb5: UUID="debce135-ac9a-426d-ad1c-f195eebfa64e" TYPE="swap" PARTUUID="00026846-05"
/dev/sdb1: UUID="dba513cf-01c7-4ba3-b17e-ed0cf8aedf05" TYPE="ext4" PARTUUID="00026846-01"
/dev/sda1: LABEL="Files" UUID="d2350e92-0df8-4736-9a35-87490b711ef5" TYPE="ext4" PARTUUID="04033ca9-01"
/dev/sdc1: LABEL="D_DISK" UUID="0A008D13008D0743" TYPE="ntfs" PARTUUID="9a67ebf9-01"
```

@Nmath-- I did remove some parts for clarity.  The original output block above has been edited to show the full output.

Comment: How much space have you got left on that partition? Execute `sudo blkid` and paste the answer into your question, using the **EDIT** button. And please state your Ubuntu Version!

Comment: Please run `sudo apt clean` to clean package cache and then retry with `sudo apt upgrade`. You probably have broken download.