# Cannot run apt-get upgrade

Tags: apt, upgrade, dpkg, configure

I run `sudo apt-get upgrade -y` after `sudo apt-get clean && sudo apt-get update`, this is the full output I get:

```
Building dependency tree... Done
Reading state information... Done
Calculating upgrade... Done
The following packages have been kept back:
  evolution-data-server gir1.2-gweather-3.0 git git-all git-cvs git-email git-gui git-man
  git-mediawiki git-svn gitk gitweb gjs gnome-calendar gnome-settings-daemon
  gnome-settings-daemon-common gnome-shell gnome-shell-common gnome-shell-extension-ubuntu-dock
  guile-2.2-libs libcamel-1.2-62 libebackend-1.2-10 libebook-1.2-20 libebook-contacts-1.2-3
  libecal-2.0-1 libedata-book-1.2-26 libedata-cal-2.0-1 libedataserver-1.2-26
  libedataserverui-1.2-3 libgirepository-1.0-1 libgjs0g libglib-object-introspection-perl
  libglib2.0-0 libglib2.0-bin libgweather-3-16 libllvm12 libllvm12:i386 libnvidia-cfg1-470
  libnvidia-compute-470 libnvidia-compute-470:i386 libnvidia-decode-470 libnvidia-decode-470:i386
  libnvidia-encode-470 libnvidia-encode-470:i386 libnvidia-extra-470 libnvidia-fbc1-470
  libnvidia-fbc1-470:i386 libnvidia-gl-470 libnvidia-gl-470:i386 libnvidia-ifr1-470
  libnvidia-ifr1-470:i386 libp11-kit0 libpython2.7-minimal libpython2.7-stdlib libpython3.9
  libpython3.9-minimal libpython3.9-stdlib libwayland-client0 libwayland-client0:i386
  libwayland-server0 linux-generic-hwe-20.04 linux-headers-generic-hwe-20.04
  linux-image-generic-hwe-20.04 nvidia-compute-utils-470 nvidia-dkms-470 nvidia-driver-470
  nvidia-kernel-common-470 nvidia-kernel-source-470 nvidia-utils-470 p11-kit p11-kit-modules
  python2.7 python2.7-minimal python3-cffi-backend python3-gi python3-gi-cairo python3.9
  python3.9-minimal xserver-xorg-video-nvidia-470 yaru-theme-gnome-shell
The following packages will be upgraded:
  apache2 apache2-bin apache2-data apache2-utils bluez bluez-cups bluez-obexd bsdextrautils eject
  evolution-data-server-common fdisk firefox firefox-locale-en fonts-opensymbol ghostscript
  ghostscript-x gir1.2-javascriptcoregtk-4.0 gir1.2-polkit-1.0 gir1.2-webkit2-4.0 initramfs-tools
  initramfs-tools-bin initramfs-tools-core libblkid1 libbluetooth3 libegl-mesa0 libexiv2-27
  libfdisk1 libfprint-2-2 libgbm1 libgl1-mesa-dri libgl1-mesa-dri:i386 libglapi-mesa
  libglapi-mesa:i386 libglx-mesa0 libglx-mesa0:i386 libgs9 libgs9-common
  libjavascriptcoregtk-4.0-18 libmount1 libnss-systemd libnvidia-common-470 libpam-systemd
  libpolkit-agent-1-0 libpolkit-gobject-1-0 libqt5core5a libqt5dbus5 libqt5gui5 libqt5network5
  libqt5opengl5 libqt5printsupport5 libqt5widgets5 libreoffice-base-core libreoffice-calc
  libreoffice-common libreoffice-core libreoffice-draw libreoffice-gnome libreoffice-gtk3
  libreoffice-help-common libreoffice-help-en-us libreoffice-impress libreoffice-math
  libreoffice-ogltrans libreoffice-pdfimport libreoffice-style-breeze libreoffice-style-colibre
  libreoffice-style-elementary libreoffice-style-yaru libreoffice-writer libsmartcols1 libsmbclient
  libspeex1 libspeexdsp1 libsystemd0 libudev1 libuno-cppu3 libuno-cppuhelpergcc3-3
  libuno-purpenvhelpergcc3-3 libuno-sal3 libuno-salhelpergcc3-3 libuuid1 libwbclient0
  libwebkit2gtk-4.0-37 libxatracker2 linux-libc-dev mesa-va-drivers mesa-vdpau-drivers
  mesa-vulkan-drivers mesa-vulkan-drivers:i386 mount nvidia-driver-460 openssh-client policykit-1
  python3-pil python3-uno qt5-gtk-platformtheme rfkill samba-libs snapd systemd systemd-sysv
  systemd-timesyncd thunderbird thunderbird-gnome-support thunderbird-locale-en
  thunderbird-locale-en-us ubuntu-advantage-tools udev uno-libs-private ure util-linux uuid-runtime
  vim vim-common vim-runtime vim-tiny xxd
117 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 80 not upgraded.
2 not fully installed or removed.
69 standard security updates
Need to get 370 MB of archives.
After this operation, 4,551 kB of additional disk space will be used.
Get:1 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu impish-updates/main amd64 libblkid1 amd64 2.36.1-8ubuntu2.2 [97.9 kB]
Get:2 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu impish-updates/main amd64 libuuid1 amd64 2.36.1-8ubuntu2.2 [23.5 kB]
Get:3 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu impish-updates/main amd64 libfdisk1 amd64 2.36.1-8ubuntu2.2 [139 kB]
Get:4 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu impish-updates/main amd64 libmount1 amd64 2.36.1-8ubuntu2.2 [117 kB]
Get:5 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu impish-updates/main amd64 libsmartcols1 amd64 2.36.1-8ubuntu2.2 [49.8 kB]
Get:6 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu impish-updates/main amd64 fdisk amd64 2.36.1-8ubuntu2.2 [121 kB]
Get:7 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu impish-updates/main amd64 util-linux amd64 2.36.1-8ubuntu2.2 [1,014 kB]
Get:8 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu impish-updates/main amd64 systemd-timesyncd amd64 248.3-1ubuntu8.2 [30.8 kB]
Get:9 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu impish-updates/main amd64 libsystemd0 amd64 248.3-1ubuntu8.2 [307 kB]
Get:10 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu impish-updates/main amd64 systemd-sysv amd64 248.3-1ubuntu8.2 [10.5 kB]
Get:11 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu impish-updates/main amd64 libnss-systemd amd64 248.3-1ubuntu8.2 [126 kB]
Get:12 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu impish-updates/main amd64 libpam-systemd amd64 248.3-1ubuntu8.2 [199 kB]
Get:13 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu impish-updates/main amd64 systemd amd64 248.3-1ubuntu8.2 [4,405 kB]
Get:14 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu impish-updates/main amd64 bluez amd64 5.60-0ubuntu2.2 [1,082 kB]
Get:15 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu impish-updates/main amd64 udev amd64 248.3-1ubuntu8.2 [1,518 kB]
Get:16 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu impish-updates/main amd64 libudev1 amd64 248.3-1ubuntu8.2 [76.2 kB]
Get:17 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu impish-updates/main amd64 mount amd64 2.36.1-8ubuntu2.2 [110 kB]
Get:18 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu impish-updates/main amd64 bsdextrautils amd64 2.36.1-8ubuntu2.2 [74.8 kB]
Get:19 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu impish-updates/main amd64 uuid-runtime amd64 2.36.1-8ubuntu2.2 [31.0 kB]
Get:20 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu impish-updates/main amd64 apache2 amd64 2.4.48-3.1ubuntu3.2 [97.8 kB]
Get:21 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu impish-updates/main amd64 apache2-bin amd64 2.4.48-3.1ubuntu3.2 [1,327 kB]
Get:22 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu impish-updates/main amd64 apache2-data all 2.4.48-3.1ubuntu3.2 [165 kB]
Get:23 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu impish-updates/main amd64 apache2-utils amd64 2.4.48-3.1ubuntu3.2 [88.9 kB]
Get:24 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu impish-updates/main amd64 libsmbclient amd64 2:4.13.17~dfsg-0ubuntu0.21.10.1 [65.9 kB]
Get:25 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu impish-updates/main amd64 libwbclient0 amd64 2:4.13.17~dfsg-0ubuntu0.21.10.1 [265 kB]
Get:26 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu impish-updates/main amd64 samba-libs amd64 2:4.13.17~dfsg-0ubuntu0.21.10.1 [6,196 kB]
Get:27 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu impish-updates/main amd64 eject amd64 2.36.1-8ubuntu2.2 [26.5 kB]
Get:28 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu impish-updates/main amd64 ubuntu-advantage-tools amd64 27.6~21.10.1 [854 kB]
Get:29 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu impish-updates/main amd64 vim amd64 2:8.2.2434-3ubuntu3.2 [1,615 kB]
Get:30 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu impish-updates/main amd64 vim-tiny amd64 2:8.2.2434-3ubuntu3.2 [676 kB]
Get:31 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu impish-updates/main amd64 vim-runtime all 2:8.2.2434-3ubuntu3.2 [6,701 kB]
Get:32 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu impish-updates/main amd64 xxd amd64 2:8.2.2434-3ubuntu3.2 [51.2 kB]
Get:33 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu impish-updates/main amd64 vim-common all 2:8.2.2434-3ubuntu3.2 [81.3 kB]
Get:34 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu impish-updates/main amd64 openssh-client amd64 1:8.4p1-6ubuntu2.1 [771 kB]
Get:35 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu impish-updates/main amd64 bluez-cups amd64 5.60-0ubuntu2.2 [26.3 kB]
Get:36 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu impish-updates/main amd64 bluez-obexd amd64 5.60-0ubuntu2.2 [218 kB]
Get:37 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu impish-updates/main amd64 evolution-data-server-common all 3.40.4-1ubuntu1 [19.8 kB]
Get:38 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu impish-updates/main amd64 firefox amd64 96.0+build2-0ubuntu0.21.10.1 [61.8 MB]
Get:39 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu impish-updates/main amd64 firefox-locale-en amd64 96.0+build2-0ubuntu0.21.10.1 [677 kB]
Get:40 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu impish-updates/main amd64 fonts-opensymbol all 2:102.12+LibO7.2.5-0ubuntu0.21.10.1 [102 kB]
Get:41 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu impish-updates/main amd64 ghostscript-x amd64 9.54.0~dfsg1-0ubuntu2.1 [48.6 kB]
Get:42 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu impish-updates/main amd64 ghostscript amd64 9.54.0~dfsg1-0ubuntu2.1 [49.5 kB]
Get:43 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu impish-updates/main amd64 libgs9 amd64 9.54.0~dfsg1-0ubuntu2.1 [4,689 kB]
Get:44 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu impish-updates/main amd64 libgs9-common all 9.54.0~dfsg1-0ubuntu2.1 [748 kB]
Get:45 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu impish-updates/main amd64 gir1.2-webkit2-4.0 amd64 2.34.4-0ubuntu0.21.10.1 [91.2 kB]
Get:46 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu impish-updates/main amd64 libwebkit2gtk-4.0-37 amd64 2.34.4-0ubuntu0.21.10.1 [15.1 MB]
Get:47 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu impish-updates/main amd64 gir1.2-javascriptcoregtk-4.0 amd64 2.34.4-0ubuntu0.21.10.1 [30.7 kB]
Get:48 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu impish-updates/main amd64 libjavascriptcoregtk-4.0-18 amd64 2.34.4-0ubuntu0.21.10.1 [6,808 kB]
Get:49 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu impish-updates/main amd64 policykit-1 amd64 0.105-31ubuntu0.1 [89.0 kB]
Get:50 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu impish-updates/main amd64 gir1.2-polkit-1.0 amd64 0.105-31ubuntu0.1 [7,692 B]
Get:51 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu impish-updates/main amd64 libpolkit-agent-1-0 amd64 0.105-31ubuntu0.1 [16.8 kB]
Get:52 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu impish-updates/main amd64 libpolkit-gobject-1-0 amd64 0.105-31ubuntu0.1 [42.6 kB]
Get:53 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu impish-updates/main amd64 initramfs-tools all 0.140ubuntu6.1 [9,072 B]
Get:54 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu impish-updates/main amd64 initramfs-tools-core all 0.140ubuntu6.1 [47.4 kB]
Get:55 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu impish-updates/main amd64 initramfs-tools-bin amd64 0.140ubuntu6.1 [11.6 kB]
Get:56 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu impish-updates/main amd64 libbluetooth3 amd64 5.60-0ubuntu2.2 [86.7 kB]
Get:57 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu impish-updates/main amd64 libegl-mesa0 amd64 21.2.6-0ubuntu0.1 [107 kB]
Get:58 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu impish-updates/main amd64 libgbm1 amd64 21.2.6-0ubuntu0.1 [31.1 kB]
Get:59 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu impish-updates/main i386 libgl1-mesa-dri i386 21.2.6-0ubuntu0.1 [11.4 MB]
Get:60 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu impish-updates/main amd64 libgl1-mesa-dri amd64 21.2.6-0ubuntu0.1 [11.7 MB]
Get:61 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu impish-updates/main amd64 libglx-mesa0 amd64 21.2.6-0ubuntu0.1 [157 kB]
Get:62 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu impish-updates/main i386 libglx-mesa0 i386 21.2.6-0ubuntu0.1 [167 kB]
Get:63 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu impish-updates/main i386 libglapi-mesa i386 21.2.6-0ubuntu0.1 [37.7 kB]
Get:64 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu impish-updates/main amd64 libglapi-mesa amd64 21.2.6-0ubuntu0.1 [35.2 kB]
Get:65 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu impish-updates/main amd64 libexiv2-27 amd64 0.27.3-3ubuntu4.1 [821 kB]
Get:66 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu impish-updates/main amd64 libfprint-2-2 amd64 1:1.90.7+git20210222+tod1-0ubuntu4~21.10.2 [240 kB]
Get:67 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu impish-updates/restricted amd64 libnvidia-common-470 all 470.103.01-0ubuntu0.21.10.1 [10.9 kB]
Get:68 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu impish-updates/universe amd64 libqt5core5a amd64 5.15.2+dfsg-12ubuntu1.1 [2,004 kB]
Get:69 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu impish-updates/universe amd64 libqt5dbus5 amd64 5.15.2+dfsg-12ubuntu1.1 [222 kB]
Get:70 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu impish-updates/universe amd64 libqt5network5 amd64 5.15.2+dfsg-12ubuntu1.1 [731 kB]
Get:71 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu impish-updates/universe amd64 libqt5gui5 amd64 5.15.2+dfsg-12ubuntu1.1 [3,720 kB]
Get:72 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu impish-updates/universe amd64 libqt5widgets5 amd64 5.15.2+dfsg-12ubuntu1.1 [2,559 kB]
Get:73 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu impish-updates/universe amd64 libqt5opengl5 amd64 5.15.2+dfsg-12ubuntu1.1 [153 kB]
Get:74 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu impish-updates/universe amd64 libqt5printsupport5 amd64 5.15.2+dfsg-12ubuntu1.1 [214 kB]
Get:75 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu impish-updates/main amd64 libuno-sal3 amd64 1:7.2.5-0ubuntu0.21.10.1 [186 kB]
Get:76 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu impish-updates/main amd64 libuno-salhelpergcc3-3 amd64 1:7.2.5-0ubuntu0.21.10.1 [17.3 kB]
Get:77 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu impish-updates/main amd64 libuno-cppu3 amd64 1:7.2.5-0ubuntu0.21.10.1 [90.7 kB]
Get:78 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu impish-updates/main amd64 libuno-purpenvhelpergcc3-3 amd64 1:7.2.5-0ubuntu0.21.10.1 [15.8 kB]
Get:79 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu impish-updates/main amd64 ure amd64 1:7.2.5-0ubuntu0.21.10.1 [1,314 kB]
Get:80 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu impish-updates/main amd64 libuno-cppuhelpergcc3-3 amd64 1:7.2.5-0ubuntu0.21.10.1 [337 kB]
Get:81 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu impish-updates/main amd64 uno-libs-private amd64 1:7.2.5-0ubuntu0.21.10.1 [240 kB]
Get:82 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu impish-updates/main amd64 libreoffice-calc amd64 1:7.2.5-0ubuntu0.21.10.1 [8,345 kB]
Get:83 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu impish-updates/main amd64 libreoffice-draw amd64 1:7.2.5-0ubuntu0.21.10.1 [3,208 kB]
Get:84 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu impish-updates/main amd64 libreoffice-writer amd64 1:7.2.5-0ubuntu0.21.10.1 [10.2 MB]
Get:85 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu impish-updates/main amd64 libreoffice-help-en-us all 1:7.2.5-0ubuntu0.21.10.1 [1,583 kB]
Get:86 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu impish-updates/main amd64 libreoffice-help-common all 1:7.2.5-0ubuntu0.21.10.1 [2,763 kB]
Get:87 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu impish-updates/main amd64 libreoffice-math amd64 1:7.2.5-0ubuntu0.21.10.1 [567 kB]
Get:88 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu impish-updates/main amd64 libreoffice-common all 1:7.2.5-0ubuntu0.21.10.1 [23.4 MB]
Get:89 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu impish-updates/main amd64 libreoffice-gnome amd64 1:7.2.5-0ubuntu0.21.10.1 [72.7 kB]
Get:90 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu impish-updates/main amd64 libreoffice-gtk3 amd64 1:7.2.5-0ubuntu0.21.10.1 [503 kB]
Get:91 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu impish-updates/main amd64 python3-uno amd64 1:7.2.5-0ubuntu0.21.10.1 [148 kB]
Get:92 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu impish-updates/main amd64 libreoffice-base-core amd64 1:7.2.5-0ubuntu0.21.10.1 [981 kB]
Get:93 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu impish-updates/main amd64 libreoffice-impress amd64 1:7.2.5-0ubuntu0.21.10.1 [1,366 kB]
Get:94 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu impish-updates/main amd64 libreoffice-core amd64 1:7.2.5-0ubuntu0.21.10.1 [40.0 MB]
Get:95 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu impish-updates/main amd64 libreoffice-style-colibre all 1:7.2.5-0ubuntu0.21.10.1 [1,275 kB]
Get:96 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu impish-updates/main amd64 libreoffice-style-breeze all 1:7.2.5-0ubuntu0.21.10.1 [3,059 kB]
Get:97 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu impish-updates/main amd64 libreoffice-style-elementary all 1:7.2.5-0ubuntu0.21.10.1 [7,987 kB]
Get:98 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu impish-updates/main amd64 libreoffice-style-yaru all 1:7.2.5-0ubuntu0.21.10.1 [3,234 kB]
Get:99 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu impish-updates/main amd64 libspeex1 amd64 1.2~rc1.2-1.1ubuntu1.21.10.1 [57.9 kB]
Get:100 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu impish-updates/main amd64 libspeexdsp1 amd64 1.2~rc1.2-1.1ubuntu1.21.10.1 [42.4 kB]
Get:101 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu impish-updates/main amd64 libxatracker2 amd64 21.2.6-0ubuntu0.1 [1,956 kB]
Get:102 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu impish-updates/main amd64 linux-libc-dev amd64 5.13.0-28.31 [1,291 kB]
Get:103 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu impish-updates/universe amd64 mesa-va-drivers amd64 21.2.6-0ubuntu0.1 [3,154 kB]
Get:104 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu impish-updates/main amd64 mesa-vdpau-drivers amd64 21.2.6-0ubuntu0.1 [3,294 kB]
Get:105 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu impish-updates/main amd64 mesa-vulkan-drivers amd64 21.2.6-0ubuntu0.1 [5,533 kB]
Get:106 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu impish-updates/main i386 mesa-vulkan-drivers i386 21.2.6-0ubuntu0.1 [5,359 kB]
Get:107 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu impish-updates/restricted amd64 nvidia-driver-460 amd64 470.103.01-0ubuntu0.21.10.1 [7,382 B]
Get:108 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu impish-updates/main amd64 python3-pil amd64 8.1.2+dfsg-0.3ubuntu0.1 [406 kB]
Get:109 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu impish-updates/universe amd64 qt5-gtk-platformtheme amd64 5.15.2+dfsg-12ubuntu1.1 [130 kB]
Get:110 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu impish-updates/main amd64 rfkill amd64 2.36.1-8ubuntu2.2 [19.5 kB]
Get:111 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu impish-updates/main amd64 snapd amd64 2.54.2+21.10ubuntu1 [22.5 MB]
Get:112 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu impish-updates/main amd64 thunderbird-locale-en amd64 1:91.5.0+build1-0ubuntu0.21.10.1 [929 kB]
Get:113 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu impish-updates/main amd64 thunderbird amd64 1:91.5.0+build1-0ubuntu0.21.10.1 [60.5 MB]
Get:114 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu impish-updates/main amd64 thunderbird-gnome-support amd64 1:91.5.0+build1-0ubuntu0.21.10.1 [8,634 B]
Get:115 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu impish-updates/main amd64 thunderbird-locale-en-us all 1:91.5.0+build1-0ubuntu0.21.10.1 [9,264 B]
Get:116 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu impish-updates/main amd64 libreoffice-ogltrans all 1:7.2.5-0ubuntu0.21.10.1 [7,298 B]
Get:117 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu impish-updates/main amd64 libreoffice-pdfimport all 1:7.2.5-0ubuntu0.21.10.1 [6,260 B]
Fetched 370 MB in 1min 19s (4,707 kB/s)                                                             
Extracting templates from packages: 100%
Preconfiguring packages ...
dpkg (subprocess): unable to execute split package reassembly (dpkg-split): No such file or directory
dpkg: error processing archive /var/cache/apt/archives/libblkid1_2.36.1-8ubuntu2.2_amd64.deb (--unpack):
 subprocess dpkg-split returned error exit status 2
Errors were encountered while processing:
 /var/cache/apt/archives/libblkid1_2.36.1-8ubuntu2.2_amd64.deb
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

I believe there are some dpkg packages are missing, but I cannot reinstall dpkg.`ls -a /usr/bin/dpkg*`:

```
/usr/bin/dpkg  /usr/bin/dpkg-deb
```

Updated by comments:

`$sudo apt-get autoremove`:

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree... Done
Reading state information... Done
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 197 not upgraded.
2 not fully installed or removed.
After this operation, 0 B of additional disk space will be used.
Setting up language-selector-common (0.216) ...
dpkg: error: unable to execute dpkg-query (dpkg-query): No such file or directory
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/bin/py3compile", line 319, in <module>
    main()
  File "/usr/bin/py3compile", line 298, in main
    compile(files, versions,
  File "/usr/bin/py3compile", line 183, in compile
    for fn, versions_to_compile in filter_files(files, e_patterns, versions):
  File "/usr/bin/py3compile", line 128, in filter_files
    for fpath in files:
  File "/usr/share/python3/debpython/files.py", line 71, in filter_public
    for fn in files:
  File "/usr/share/python3/debpython/files.py", line 53, in from_package
    raise Exception("cannot get content of %s" % package_name)
Exception: cannot get content of language-selector-common
dpkg: error processing package language-selector-common (--configure):
 subprocess installed post-installation script returned error exit status 1
No apport report written because the error message indicates its a followup error from a previous failure.
     dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of language-selector-gnome:
 language-selector-gnome depends on language-selector-common (= 0.216); however:
  Package language-selector-common is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing package language-selector-gnome (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
Errors were encountered while processing:
 language-selector-common
 language-selector-gnome
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

`sudo dpkg --configure -a`

```
Setting up language-selector-common (0.216) ...
dpkg: error: unable to execute dpkg-query (dpkg-query): No such file or directory
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/bin/py3compile", line 319, in <module>
    main()
  File "/usr/bin/py3compile", line 298, in main
    compile(files, versions,
  File "/usr/bin/py3compile", line 183, in compile
    for fn, versions_to_compile in filter_files(files, e_patterns, versions):
  File "/usr/bin/py3compile", line 128, in filter_files
    for fpath in files:
  File "/usr/share/python3/debpython/files.py", line 71, in filter_public
    for fn in files:
  File "/usr/share/python3/debpython/files.py", line 53, in from_package
    raise Exception("cannot get content of %s" % package_name)
Exception: cannot get content of language-selector-common
dpkg: error processing package language-selector-common (--configure):
 subprocess installed post-installation script returned error exit status 1
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of language-selector-gnome:
 language-selector-gnome depends on language-selector-common (= 0.216); however:
  Package language-selector-common is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing package language-selector-gnome (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
Errors were encountered while processing:
 language-selector-common
 language-selector-gnome
```

`sudo apt-get install --fix-broken`:

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree... Done
Reading state information... Done
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 197 not upgraded.
2 not fully installed or removed.
After this operation, 0 B of additional disk space will be used.
Setting up language-selector-common (0.216) ...
dpkg: error: unable to execute dpkg-query (dpkg-query): No such file or directory
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/bin/py3compile", line 319, in <module>
    main()
  File "/usr/bin/py3compile", line 298, in main
    compile(files, versions,
  File "/usr/bin/py3compile", line 183, in compile
    for fn, versions_to_compile in filter_files(files, e_patterns, versions):
  File "/usr/bin/py3compile", line 128, in filter_files
    for fpath in files:
  File "/usr/share/python3/debpython/files.py", line 71, in filter_public
    for fn in files:
  File "/usr/share/python3/debpython/files.py", line 53, in from_package
    raise Exception("cannot get content of %s" % package_name)
Exception: cannot get content of language-selector-common
dpkg: error processing package language-selector-common (--configure):
 subprocess installed post-installation script returned error exit status 1
No apport report written because the error message indicates its a followup error from a previous failure.
     dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of language-selector-gnome:
 language-selector-gnome depends on language-selector-common (= 0.216); however:
  Package language-selector-common is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing package language-selector-gnome (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
Errors were encountered while processing:
 language-selector-common
 language-selector-gnome
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

`sudo apt-get install aptitude`:

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree... Done
Reading state information... Done
The following additional packages will be installed:
  aptitude-common libcwidget4 libxapian30
Suggested packages:
  apt-xapian-index aptitude-doc-en | aptitude-doc debtags tasksel libcwidget-dev xapian-tools
The following NEW packages will be installed:
  aptitude aptitude-common libcwidget4 libxapian30
0 upgraded, 4 newly installed, 0 to remove and 197 not upgraded.
2 not fully installed or removed.
Need to get 3,827 kB of archives.
After this operation, 17.3 MB of additional disk space will be used.
Do you want to continue? [Y/n] y
Get:1 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu impish/universe amd64 aptitude-common all 0.8.13-3ubuntu1 [1,719 kB]
Get:2 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu impish/universe amd64 libcwidget4 amd64 0.5.18-5build1 [306 kB]
Get:3 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu impish/universe amd64 libxapian30 amd64 1.4.18-3build1 [702 kB]
Get:4 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu impish/universe amd64 aptitude amd64 0.8.13-3ubuntu1 [1,100 kB]
Fetched 3,827 kB in 2s (2,383 kB/s) 
dpkg (subprocess): unable to execute split package reassembly (dpkg-split): No such file or directory
dpkg: error processing archive /var/cache/apt/archives/aptitude-common_0.8.13-3ubuntu1_all.deb (--unpack):
 subprocess dpkg-split returned error exit status 2
dpkg (subprocess): unable to execute split package reassembly (dpkg-split): No such file or directory
dpkg: error processing archive /var/cache/apt/archives/libcwidget4_0.5.18-5build1_amd64.deb (--unpack):
 subprocess dpkg-split returned error exit status 2
dpkg (subprocess): unable to execute split package reassembly (dpkg-split): No such file or directory
dpkg: error processing archive /var/cache/apt/archives/libxapian30_1.4.18-3build1_amd64.deb (--unpack):
 subprocess dpkg-split returned error exit status 2
dpkg (subprocess): unable to execute split package reassembly (dpkg-split): No such file or directory
dpkg: error processing archive /var/cache/apt/archives/aptitude_0.8.13-3ubuntu1_amd64.deb (--unpack):
 subprocess dpkg-split returned error exit status 2
No apport report written because MaxReports is reached already
                                                              Errors were encountered while processing:
 /var/cache/apt/archives/aptitude-common_0.8.13-3ubuntu1_all.deb
 /var/cache/apt/archives/libcwidget4_0.5.18-5build1_amd64.deb
 /var/cache/apt/archives/libxapian30_1.4.18-3build1_amd64.deb
 /var/cache/apt/archives/aptitude_0.8.13-3ubuntu1_amd64.deb
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

`sudo apt install language-selector-common language-selector-gnome`:

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree... Done
Reading state information... Done
language-selector-common is already the newest version (0.216).
language-selector-gnome is already the newest version (0.216).
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 197 not upgraded.
2 not fully installed or removed.
After this operation, 0 B of additional disk space will be used.
Do you want to continue? [Y/n] y
Setting up language-selector-common (0.216) ...
dpkg: error: unable to execute dpkg-query (dpkg-query): No such file or directory
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/bin/py3compile", line 319, in <module>
    main()
  File "/usr/bin/py3compile", line 298, in main
    compile(files, versions,
  File "/usr/bin/py3compile", line 183, in compile
    for fn, versions_to_compile in filter_files(files, e_patterns, versions):
  File "/usr/bin/py3compile", line 128, in filter_files
    for fpath in files:
  File "/usr/share/python3/debpython/files.py", line 71, in filter_public
    for fn in files:
  File "/usr/share/python3/debpython/files.py", line 53, in from_package
    raise Exception("cannot get content of %s" % package_name)
Exception: cannot get content of language-selector-common
dpkg: error processing package language-selector-common (--configure):
 subprocess installed post-installation script returned error exit status 1
No apport report written because the error message indicates its a followup error from a previous fai
lure.
     dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of language-selector-gnome:
 language-selector-gnome depends on language-selector-common (= 0.216); however:
  Package language-selector-common is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing package language-selector-gnome (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
Errors were encountered while processing:
 language-selector-common
 language-selector-gnome
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

I tried many different resources online but couldn't really solve the issue. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Same question with no answer yet but some suggestions in the comments. https://askubuntu.com/questions/1360275/no-such-file-or-directory-error-in-dpkg-during-apt-upgrade

Comment: Please [edit] to add the FULL error message. The part of the error you inserted is not enough for troubleshooting this. Also, include the output of `sudo apt update`

Comment: Smell like a broken C package. Have you tried apply `$ sudo apt-get autoremove`, `$ sudo dpkg --fix-broken`, `$ sudo apt-get autoclean` before `$ sudo apt-get update` ?

Comment: The error message `sudo apt-get autoremove` gives is updated in the post.

Comment: Mistake: please `$ sudo dpkg --configure -a`.

Comment: Do `$ sudo apt-get install --fix-broken` (there's the argument)

Comment: try to install aptitude and do the upgrade

Comment: also run `sudo apt install language-selector-common language-selector-gnome` and paste the output

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Package dbus is not configured yet](https://askubuntu.com/questions/202321/package-dbus-is-not-configured-yet) and [Can't upgrade/update ubuntu 18.04 as apt/dpkg error is showing up](https://askubuntu.com/q/1056780/)

Comment: I don't have aptitude installed so when I try to run the commands in the first link it asks me to install it using apt which again throws similar errors. For the second link, as a person with not so much experience with linux, I'm not really sure how to follow the procedure for HPLIP.

Comment: seems like your impish upgrades are not correctly. try to configure manually, run `sudo dpkg --configure language-selector-common language-selector-gnome` and then `cd /var/cache/apt/archives/ && sudo dpkg -i *.deb`.

Comment: The manual configuration also gives a similar error:

```dpkg: error: unable to execute dpkg-query (dpkg-query): No such file or directory
dpkg: error processing package language-selector-common (--configure):
 subprocess installed post-installation script returned error exit status 1
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of language-selector-gnome:
 language-selector-gnome depends on language-selector-common (= 0.216); however:
  Package language-selector-common is not configured yet.
```
(Cut some parts of the message to fit in a comment)